# Nginx: Have two separate servers under the same port

Tags: nginx

For examples sake; Let's say I have two separate web applications running on my machine:

`http://127.0.0.1:8080` - Backend: Returns JSON.

`http://127.0.0.1:8000` - Frontend: Returns HTML, CSS, JS, etc.

What I want to do is something like what a [Mastodon](https://joinmastodon.org/) instance does out of the box: Have both servers listen under the same port -`80`- and deliver their respective content according to headers supplied by the HTTP request. To get an idea of what I mean, take the following `curl` commands targeting a the profile of a Mastodon user:

```
$ curl https://mastodon.social/@Gargron
```

```
$ curl -H 'Accept: application/json' https://mastodon.social/@Gargron
```

The first one, when executed, will respond with the HTML of the frontend. Doing the same with the second command will return JSON provided by the API.

If possible, can an Nginx configuration replicate this kind of behavior, using the two servers I'm running?

Comment: Whatever handles the request just routes appropriately, assuming Mastodon even has a separate frontend and backend.